# Click Framelayout não funciona com Listview dentro

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho a seguinte situação: Possuo um layout principal que contem um listview dentro. Esse listview mantém certa distância das bordas do layout e posicionei um Layout Externo literalmente por cima desse listview ocupando toda a tela.
O problema em questão é que o click do Layout Externo (Container) só funciona nos locais onde o listview não ocupa, caso seja uma area mais centrada na tela o clique simplesmente não funciona.

[image: Imagem para exemplificar a questão]

Preciso que o clique no container ocorra mesmo clicando em qualquer parte em que o listview esteja presente.
Já dei uma lida na documentação sobre isso mas realmente não consegui implementar nada que remova o clique da lista e deixe apenas o clique do Container.

Caso tenham sugestões do que pode ser feito agradeço desde já.

Comment: Me corrija se entendi errado, você tem um listview que ocupa todo seu layout, e por cima deste listview você tem um frame layout, seria isso? Se sim, por quê? Se for o caso do seu frame layout sobrepor o list, você pode colocar o list como invisível, desta forma não seria possível interagir com ela.

Comment: Vitor foi uma questão de necessidade implementar isso aqui, mas seria basicamente isso mesmo. Mas preciso que o listview continue exibindo os itens da lista mas ao invés de eu rolar a lista e escolher um item especifico o clique no 'card' todo (que seria o framelayout) me leva para o próximo item de forma automática.

Comment: Se puder editar a pergunta com algumas imagens de como você quer que funcione ficaria mais fácil de ajudar, acho que não consegui entender ainda de forma clara.

Comment: Vitor editei a questão e coloquei uma imagem explicando a situação.